# Xcode compiler doesn't see files after update to v6.3?

Tags: ios, xcode

After update i have errors with folders in my project.

```
 file not found
```

[image: import]
and if i comment this import, i get this

```
Unknown class FLLoginVC in Interface Builder!
```

But they are in project [image: files]and in copy bundle [image: copy bundle] file.
If i add my `FLLoginVC.h` and `FLLoginVC.m` to '`Copy Bundle Resources`', it works, but if i add full folder hierarchy, it doesn't.

Comment: Not enough information.  Show the complete error message as that looks like a compiler error, however that conflicts with the "in copy bundle" statement. Confusing.

Comment: How about commenting out `#import "FLDefaultSHKConfigurator.h"` and adding `#import "FLLoginVC.h"`?

Comment: Wait, your post is about several different bugs. It complains about *FLDefaultSHKConfigurator.h* as well as the storyboard and the launchscreen. Are you sure you have all of them in your project? You might want to remove them (**not** into trash) from inside Xcode. Then add them again and make sure they are copied into the folder. If it complains uncheck *copy to project folder* and add them. If the problem still occurs try cleaning your project with `cmd` + `shift` + `k` after restarting Xcode and your Mac.

Comment: you accidentally added those files with _folders_ not with virtual _groups_. remove the reference and add them with _groups_ only.

Comment: holex, thx. added groups, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add the whole folder to copy bundle resources. You select the .m and go into sidebar, first tab, and check your current target (so that the code compiles for that target). You only copy images and data files to bundle.